# QDataStream Serialization Problem

Tags: qt, stream

Here goes my Code first.

```
QByteArray buff;
QDataStream stream(&buff, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_7);
stream << 5;
stream << 6;
qDebug() << buff;
int x;
int y;
stream >> x >> y;
qDebug() << x << y;
```

I expect x be 5 and y be 6. But its showing 0 0
Here is the output

```
"
0 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Frank mentioned the `QDataStream` is still at the end position (after writing your data). If you don't want to create a new stream, it should also be possible to call `stream.reset()` to put the stream's internal position to the beginning. Or something like `stream.seek(0)`.

Comment: This helped me with a different (but related) issue: It turns out that calling `clear()` on a QByteArray that backs a QDataStream does not reset the stream position! So, `stream << (int)5; buff.clear(); stream << (int)6;` will cause `buff.size()` to report `8`, not `4`. Resetting the stream is required.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
QByteArray buff;
QDataStream stream(&buff, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
stream << 5;
stream << 6;
qDebug() << buff.toHex();

int x;
int y;

// This line will move the internal QBuffer to position 0
stream.device()->reset();

stream >> x >> y;
qDebug() << x << y;
```

Output:

```
"0000000500000006" 
5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't read/write like this from/to a QByteArray using a single QDataStream, at the same time, due to the data stream's internal state (stream position). Try with a second QDataStream for reading.